# counting textures created grouping by 1d ,2d ,3d in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

gDebugger shows me textures that created in the application grouping by dimensions . I want also to count number of textures created from start in my  app to check leak of textures .I didn't see any OpenGl function directly return count of created texture ids;what is the best way to count textures created in application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no GL function that would do it in batch, but just for debug purposes, you can simply iterate over all "possible" ids (thus, numbers), and check with `glIsTexture`:

```
const unsigned reasonably_big_value = 100000;
for (unsigned i = 0; i < reasonably_big_value; ++i) {
    if (glIsTexture(i)) {
       // count it somehow   
    }
}
```

There's no way, at least one I'm aware of, of getting the texture dimensionality at runtime. [`glGetTexLevelParameter`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetTexLevelParameter.xml) requires a `target` parameter, so you're on your own with that.

gDEBugger acts as a middleman and traces all GL calls, IIRC, so it can have its own mirror texture registry.

Comment: Do glGentexture Create texture with smallest free id?this code is usable when glGentexture Create texture with smallest free id.

Comment: It isn't *required* to, I think, but pretty much all implementations allocate consecutive numbers starting with 1.

Comment: my question is :if I have for example 1,2,3,4,5, and delete 3 can i be sure that then next genereted id is 3?

Comment: You have to check for yourself, but does it really matter? `glIsTexture` will return `false` on 3 if it's empty, but you can proceed and check next numbers anyway.

Comment: how to test what type the texture is? 2d, 3d 1d? use this glgettexlevelparam and for each texture pass gl_texture_1d, _2d, _3d as a target (and somehow cope with gl_invalid_enum/operation error) ?

Comment: @fen No, that would not help. I've explicitely stated that in my answer.

Comment: really no:).by choosing a reasonably big value no.